# Repository class does not exist (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-4, psr-0

I am using the Repository pattern in my current project. When I try and access the route I get this error

```
ReflectionException
Class Repositories\UserRepository does not exist
```

My folder structure is like so

```
- Respositories
-- UserRepository
```

In my controller I am doing

```
use \Repositories\UserRepository;

class UsersController extends ApiController {

protected $user;

public function __construct(UserRepository $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

In the UserRepository

```
<?php namespace \Repositories

class UserRepository {
```

I am autoloading in composer

```
"psr-0": {
   "Respositories": "app/"
}
```

Are my namespaces correct? I can not workout why it can't find the class.

Comment: I don't think you're meant to prefix a namespace with a backslash. Try removing that. Also, you can omit the backslash prefix on your `use` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Don't use prefixed back slashes when defining the namespace.

```
// No
<?php namespace \Repositories;

// Yes
<?php namespace Repositories;
```

2) Check your spelling. In your composer.json file, you have **Respositories** instead of Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your laravel hasn't load your repository, if thus, just simply run this

```
command composer dumpautoload
```

if this occurred on your deployment server, have read this article regarding on this error http://www.tagipuru.xyz/2016/07/09/repository-class-does-not-exist-in-laravel/